# ObservableCollection not working as expected, mvvm light

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, mvvm-light, observablecollection

What I did is a search function to search for events.
My problem here is that there's a property that fires up when i enter the page and set my `ObservableCollection` count to 0, but there are events details in my database.
How this should have work is that when i enter on the page there is a relay command that executes and retrieve all data from database and place it into the observable collection and display the event names into a `ListBox`. It I only when I enter a character then after it detect the events.

Here are my codes:

xaml:

```
<Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Loaded">
        <Core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Searchfromhomepage.EventSearch, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
</Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">

    <Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <EntranceThemeTransition/>
        </TransitionCollection>
    </Grid.ChildrenTransitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <!--<TextBox  x:Name="txtSearch" Background="White"  Text="{Binding Path=HomePage.TxtEntered, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  FontSize="30"  Height="57" Margin="19,10,19,0" Grid.Row="1" />-->


    <TextBox x:Name="txtTest2"  Text="{Binding Searchfromhomepage.Filter, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

    <Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ContentRoot" Margin="19,9.667,19,0">
        <ListBox Background="Black"  x:Name="listBox" FontSize="26" Margin="0,10,0,0"  ItemsSource="{Binding Searchfromhomepage.FilteredNames, Mode=OneWay}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="txtEventName" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding EventName}" Tapped="txtEventName_Tapped" IsTapEnabled="True" Foreground="White" Width="300" Margin="10,15,0,0" Height="55"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

viewmodel codes:

```
private static ObservableCollection<Event> _searchEventCollection = new ObservableCollection<Event>();

public static ObservableCollection<Event> SearchEventCollection
{
    get { return _searchEventCollection; }
    set { _searchEventCollection = value; }
}

//search from homepage event section
private RelayCommand _eventSearch;
/// <summary>
/// Gets the EventSearch.
/// </summary>
public RelayCommand EventSearch
{
    get
    {  return _eventSearch
            ?? (_eventSearch = new RelayCommand(
            async () =>
            {
                SearchEventCollection.Clear();
                var eventList = await App.MobileService.GetTable<Event>().ToListAsync();

                foreach (Event ename in eventList)
                {
                    SearchEventCollection.Add(new Event
                    {
                        Id = ename.Id,
                        EventName = ename.EventName,
                        Date = ename.Date,
                        Location = ename.Location,
                        Desc = ename.Desc
                    });
                }
            }));
    }
}


private string filter;
public String Filter
{
    get
    {
        return this.filter;
    }
    set
    {
        this.filter = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("FilteredNames");
    }
}
public List<Event> FilteredNames
{
    get
    {
        if (filter == "") 
        {
            return SearchEventCollection.ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            return (from name in SearchEventCollection where name.EventName.ToUpper().StartsWith(filter.ToUpper()) select name).ToList();
        }
    }
}
public searchfromhomepageViewModel()
{ 
    filter = "";
}
```

Comment: What's the DataContext of the page? At what point do you set it? Is the EventSearch command fired when the page is loaded? Do you have any binding errors in the Output window?

Comment: the EventSearch does fire up when the page loads. binding errors i dnt know but on the first time i enter the page nothing is displayed but still there is data in the database

Comment: That means that the binding to the EventSearch command is OK. Can you debug and put a breakpoint after "foreach (Event ename in eventList)" to see if the SearchEventCollection has all the items?

Comment: yes the SearchEventCollection has all the items but does not display any information.

Comment: Why is the ItemsSource of the ListBox not binding to SearchEventCollection?

Comment: i binded it such so as when the user types in the textbox, the listbox is filtererd. is it correct?

Comment: at first nothing is displayed, i just add a character say "A" and when i remove the "A" then the data are displayed from database.

Answer (score 0):

in your view model code set up the _eventSearch command like so

```
public RelayCommand _eventSearch = new RelayCommand(EventSearch);
```